# Does get(replicated)map load the whole data or just the reference?

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I would like to get the value of a key, however the `Map` is large so I don't want it to be completely loaded into memory. So if I do something like:

`hazelcast.getReplicatedMap(name).get(key)`

will it load the whole map into memory then get the value?

If yes, is there a way to get the value of a key without loading everything into memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** Please see @pveentjer's answer since I supposed the question was asked for client topology and answered accordingly.

It does not load the whole map but returns an instance of it. So when you call `hazelcast.getReplicatedMap(name).get(key)` only one entry - if exists, will be fetched from distributed map.

Answer (score 2):

With the replicated map the whole map is replicated to all members in the cluster. So it will always be fully in memory on those members.

On the client side, only the value is pulled into memory when you call replicatedMap.get(key)